# How to call a function which is inside another function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
   function a(){
        this.i = 10,
         function b(){
            console.log("Regular function ",this.i, this)
        }
    }
```

Here I want to call function b

Comment: Just call it as b() from within a. If you want to call it from outside of a. then assign it to a with this.b = b; then you can do var foo = new a(); foo.b();

Comment: Answer is you don't....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the use of `this` within the function, you need to call the `a` function as a "constructor function" (with the `new` keyword) or invoke it with `call()`, `apply()`, or `bind()` so that you can specify context for `this`.

And, because the `b` function uses the context of `a`, it should be either returned from the parent or declared as an instance method of `a` with `this.b = function()...`

```js
function a() {
  this.i = 10;
  
  // To make the nested function have access to the
  // parent function's instance data, you can either
  // return it from the parent or declare it as an
  // instance method of the parent (shown here):
  this.b = function(){
    console.log("Regular function ", this.i, this);
  }
}
    
// Invoke a as a constructor function
let newA = new a();

// Now call b within the context of a
newA.b();
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Scott Marcus

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the function first as shown below:

```
function a(){
    this.i = 10;
   return  function b(){
        console.log("Regular function ",this.i, this)
    }
}
```

And then call it using:

```
a()()
```

**UPDATE:** `this` keyword in the above example will point to the global scope. To make sure we use `this` within the function context we can use `call()` method on function a() and pass the object to which this will associate it's scope.

```
function a(){
    this.i = 10;
   return  b = ()=>{
        console.log("Regular function ",this.i,this)
    }
}

a.call({i:10})();
```

**Note:**   I have also used arrow method for `function b()` to keep `this` scope used within it as its `function a()'s` scope.

Comment: `a()()` not `a()b()`. Also you need to remove the comma before `return`

Comment: TYpo ... My Bad.. Just edited. Thanks for highlighting mate. Edited properly Sir. Thank you very much :)

Comment: If you call the function this way, you will be creating an `i` property on the Global object.

Comment: You are right, this will point to the global scope. I can use arrow function to handle it also. Right? Or use call()

Comment: Arrow won't work.

Comment: In the inner function I mean. See now Please Mr Scott, I have upadted my answer :)